# passing reservation id?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

i design a course reservation using php & mysql

i need to pass the specific (id) for the select course in registration from course.php to registration.php

```
<a href="registrate.php">

<input type="button" class="reserve" id="<?= $row['id'] ?>" name="Registrate" value="Registrate Now"  style="border-radius:30; width:130; height: 25; color: green; font-weight:bolder; font-size: 13"/>

</a>

<?$identified =$this-> $row['id']?>
<? echo $identified; ?>
```

problem is passing all id variable to registration

Comment: If you don't know about $_GET variables, you should go back to the drawing board :)

Comment: i just begining in php ... if u can help me hope u do

Comment: @VladPreda be kind to new coders, suggest them ways to learn the same way you did

Comment: @PERR0_HUNTER you're right. Ibrahim, you should check out a few tutorials. The most basic one would be here: http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.php What you're struggling with is in "dealing with forms".

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve passing that value "hidden" using a form

```
<form action="registrate.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?= $row['id'] ?>">
<input type="button" class="reserve" name="Registrate" value="Registrate Now"  style="border-radius:30; width:130; height: 25; color: green; font-weight:bolder; font-size: 13"/>
</form>
```

And then on your registrate.php script

```
<? $identified = $_POST['id']?>
<? echo $identified; ?>
```

an alternative is pass it through $_GET

```
<a href="registrate.php?id=<?= $row['id'] ?>">Registrate</a>
```

And then on your registrate.php script

```
<? $identified = $_GET['id']?>
<? echo $identified; ?>
```

If you are new to PHP I'd recommend you a book, such as [PHP and MySQL for Dynamic Web Sites: Visual QuickPro Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321784073) It's great for beginners

saludos

Comment: Thnx ... it's work
but there is a problem
every time it pass the same variable for course (id)
i want to pass (id) variable for the selected course only

Comment: @IbrahimNagy glad to hear that! :) remember you can always upvote answers that helped you on stackoverflow or mark them as the correct answer to your question, welcome to StackOverFlow happy posting :)

Comment: hope understand what i exactly want

Comment: @IbrahimNagy Can you explain a little further? :) sounds to me you should handle the course id through all the pages you are moving the user, you might aswell store that course ID on a $_SESSION variable so you don't need to actually pass the id on all the URL's

Comment: i think there is a way to do what i want using  ($this->id) but i get error every time i use it

Comment: @IbrahimNagy when you use $this->id that is refering to a private or public variable of a certain object, since you are not working with objects I don't think that would work for you, you'd need to post more code so I can understand what you are trying to achieve :)

Comment: here is my code

<form method="post" action="registrate.php">
<?php
$query = mysql_query("select * from courses order by id desc");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {                                        
?>
<table >
<tr>
<td style="width:160 ;padding-left: 5" class="textformat">Language</td>
<td width="130" align="center" colspan="2" style="background-color: #DDDDDD; border-radius:5px ;">
<a class="textformat"><?= $row['language'] ?></a>
</td>
<td align="center" class="textformat">Start</td>

Comment: @IbrahimNagy please paste it to http://pastebin.com/ so make it easier to read :)

Comment: <form method="post" action="registrate.php">
                                    <?php
                                    $now = time();
                                    $query = mysql_query("select * from courses order by id desc");
                                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
                                        if ($row['start'] > $now) {
                                            continue;
                                        }
                                    ?>

Comment: i make while loop to preview all course and every one has a registration button .... all what i want is to pass course (id) for the selected course to reserve the selected course only

Comment: for some reason I can't open the pastebin link that you sent, please send another link

Comment: hope u can help me ?? @perrohunter

Comment: i now i write too much but i don't have another one to help me ... hope u can :)

Comment: You need to have reputation 20 so we can start a chat, I cant open your pastebin :/ it says Unknown Paste ID!